# How to calculate scaled speed

Tags: measurements, mathematics, simulation, distance-measurement

While working on a project I faced a difficult problem.

Let's say I have car at a 1/10 scale. Now if a real car drives at 10 m/s, it would take 3 seconds to travel 30m. If we look at the scaled car and the scaled street, which is now 3m, the car would need to go at 1 m/s. That way it would travel the same car-lengths.

[image]

As much as I understand engineers use (sometimes) scaled models to figure out how the real car (or anything else) would behave and they calculate the speed by multiplying with the square root of the scale.

Both ways make sense to me depending on what you try to achieve. Since multiplying by the scale doesn't account the 'scaling of the air' and so on. But if you look at example at the top it doesn't seem right or the street needs also to be scaled in the square root?

Comment: I think you need to decide what it is you're actually interested  in. Remember, it's a model and models never fully reflect reality. Even physically constructed models, because if it did, it would just be the real thing. If fluid dynamics is your concern then you need to increase airspeed as the model size decreases (see Reynolds number). If it's something with a mass-surface area relationship such as perhaps structural failure or coasting to a stop under air resistance then you might need to make your small model more dense (square cube law).

Comment: @DKNguyen I see, what if I have multiple concerns? At 1/10 scale car that should test a realworld driving assistant, I need the tyre model to be accurate (lets say for obstacle avoidance). But what about a parking assistant, where I need everything to be in the same ratio to the car size?

Comment: Is this like a radio controlled drivable model or something?

Comment: Yes, controlled by an arduino or raspberry pi

Comment: I am not sure what concerns you have but most of the ones I can think of involve adjusting the power to weight ratio (or have a control system) and mass density so acceleration and deceleration scale linearly. Your tire material likely has to be softer too and or have some differences for things like contact area.

Comment: So scaling what? Dynamic effects? Kinematic effects or geometric?

Comment: @SolarMike I think both kinematic and geometric effects, the question is how I can scale both

Comment: I dont think this is as easy as ot sounds in this case. As you have a LOT of things that dont scale all too well. Material properties for one dont scale well as volume scales cubed but stiffness scales by square. So the wheel model is going to be awfully hard to get right. But again depends on your tolerance. To be honest though this is probably not really a big deal for your control system.

Comment: @joojaa indeed, for now it is ok if the tyre model is not realistic, it is enough if it just 'works'. So I either multply everything with the scale or the square root of it, knowing that it doesn't simulate a real car. Probably multiplying by the scale better?

Comment: It will be extremely difficult or impossible to replicate vehicle physics using a scale model due to the square cube law. My advice would be to accept that your car will not be an accurate simulation in terms of traction, drag, etc.

Comment: @Drew I agree and it's ok for the project I am working on. I just don't know what the most accurate scaling is.